# iOS 9 3D Touch Home screen Dyanamic quick action

Tags: ios, iphone, 3dtouch, quickaction

As per the Apple documentation :
**Define dynamic quick actions with the UIApplicationShortcutItem class and associated APIs.**

So i just want to know that Can we use dynamic quick actions with our custom web service APIs?. I want to pull data from API and show it in the dynamic quick action menu. Is it possible?

Comment: Yes, you can call webservice on your first app launch (Or whenever you prefer) and than you can add dynamic quick actions like you would usually do.

Comment: Thanx @Bhumit.  Actually i have to call Webservice API without launching the app. Is it possible? I have to show the API data in the quick action menu.

Comment: Not possible without launching the app.

Comment: @Bhumit Thanx.  I also thought the same just wanted confirmation on it as Apple documentation has not properly specified it. Is there any Apple documentation available for it?

I am also wondering why they specified in their doc as "Define dynamic quick actions with the UIApplicationShortcutItem class and associated APIs". They mentioned associated  APIs